# Add Previous | Next arrows near to related products

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

Greatings,

Is there a way to make Previous and Next arrows to related products, cross sell products?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how your Previous and Next arrows are setup and/or being pulled in, but at a basic level you can add in the `product_cat` to the previous_post_link() and next_post_link() calls:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/previous_post_link

```
<?php
  previous_post_link( 'Previous: %link', '%title', true, '', 'product_cat' );
?>
```